# What is in memory authentication in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication

How to use in Memory Authentication in Spring Boot version 5?

What are the best way to implement in memory authentication?

I wanted to know how can I implement in memory authentication in my Spring Boot Version 5 Application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By a simple google search you can find a lot of samples and documents for your question, as springs docs says you can use in memory authentication as below:

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService users() {
    UserDetails user = User.builder()
        .username("user")
        .password("{bcrypt}$2a$10$GRLdNijSQMUvl/au9ofL.eDwmoohzzS7.rmNSJZ.0FxO/BTk76klW")
        .roles("USER")
        .build();
    UserDetails admin = User.builder()
        .username("admin")
        .password("{bcrypt}$2a$10$GRLdNijSQMUvl/au9ofL.eDwmoohzzS7.rmNSJZ.0FxO/BTk76klW")
        .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
        .build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, admin);
}
```

for more details check the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/in-memory.html).